# 2 timer using OnTimer(UINT_PTR ID) with vc++

Tags: visual-c++, timer

I want to use 2 timer, one is for reading sensor, and another for give the command to robot, using visual studio VC++ 2010 class library.

first timer is on if the button 1 is clicked, and second timer using button 3.

but when I click button 2, my read sensor is working even though I have not press the button 1, and vice versa.

here is my program:

what is wrong with my code?

```
const int cTimer1 = 1;
const int cTimer2 = 1;

 void CENVSConfigDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
SetTimer(cTimer1,1000,NULL);
}

 void CENVSConfigDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
KillTimer(cTimer1);
}

 void CENVSConfigDlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{   
SetTimer(cTimer2,10,NULL);  
}

void CENVSConfigDlg::OnBnClickedButton4()
{
    KillTimer(cTimer2);
}

void CENVSConfigDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR ID){
if(ID==cTimer1){

    char buffer[30],tempStr[5];
    int sensor[6];

    DWORD nbytes;

    MessageBeep(0);

    //Read Sensors

    if(!WriteFile( hnd_serial, "1", 1, &nbytes, NULL )){KillTimer(cTimer1);MessageBox(L"Write Com Port fail!");return;}
    Sleep(30);
    if(!ReadFile( hnd_serial, buffer, 30, &nbytes, NULL )){KillTimer(cTimer1);MessageBox(L"Read Com Port fail!");return;}
    Sleep(300);



if(ID==cTimer2)
{
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x53) != 0)
 {
 DWORD nbytes;
if(!WriteFile( hnd_serial, "s", 1, &nbytes, NULL )){MessageBox(L"Write Com Port fail!");return;}
    Sleep(30);
 tampil.SetWindowText( (LPCTSTR)"s" ); //backward
 }

else if(GetAsyncKeyState(0x57) != 0)
{
    DWORD nbytes;
if(!WriteFile( hnd_serial, "w", 1, &nbytes, NULL )){MessageBox(L"Write Com Port fail!");return;}
    Sleep(30);
    tampil.SetWindowText( (LPCTSTR)"w" );//forward
}


}

}


}
```

Comment: ups sorry, I found the mistake.. const int cTimer2 = 1;
must be const int cTimer2 = 2;

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you found your own mistake. But your code still has some glitches.

- You are performing read, write, sleep in the timer (`WM_TIMER` message) itself. This will cause the UI thread to freeze. You should better use another thread to process, which involves something other than UI update.
- Your timer ID is named like `Timer1`, `Timer2` etc, which is not programmer friendly. You should use better names to reflect actual meaning.
- Multiple timers will not work at the same time. Again, you better use multithreading!

Comment: Thx ajax, 
I try to find timer to do at the same time, but I cannot find the methods. can you suggest me something to do it?